# Andy Timmons Carpe Diem fast vibration

Tags: guitar, technique, electric-guitar

This is a tough one :)

When I listen to this amazing track (track 14 from **"That was then, This is now"** album) I notice at 0:36 and 0:42 a very fast vibration on the G string (5th fret) which I doubt is possible using your fingers. I was wondering how exactly does he achieve this sound (its like a very fast and short vibration/trilling sound).

When I pull/release the tremolo bar (fast) it sounds like it but I was wondering how exactly he does it.

thx

Answer (score 3):

Of all that sounds exceptional on that track (and there is much that's great on the track; thanks for bringing it to my attention), the vibrato isn't. It sounds good, but it sounds like finger vibrato. There might be some points where he uses the whammy bar, but most of it sounds like finger vibrato to me.

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEKOHhaHBgI) show Tom Hess giving a phrasing lesson, and it includes a wide and fast finger vibrato.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I watched the video and it is definitely a standard finger vibrato (also in speed). If you listen very carefully to time 0:36 and 0:42 you will hear what I meant. (its very short but audible)

Comment: I watched three different Andy Timmons videos while he is playing "Carpe Diem" and there is nothing at 0:36 or 0:42 that he is not already doing with his hands. It's all in his hands.

Comment: Do  not watch the videos. listen to the studio track. I 100% positive the vibrato I mean is not the one you heard.

Comment: @VarLogRant, I heard today another track and the sound I talk about can be clearly heard at track : "That Was Then, This is Now" (From the same album) 1:26-1:28. And I really doubt it is done with by fingers

Comment: I don't know what that is, but I have an idea.

Consider the gap between the second and third strings. Here you go from G to B, which is a major third. One common lick is to bend the G string up to a note, not necessarily hitting it, with your middle and ring finger, then play that note on the B string, fretting it with your index finger. It is a canonical Chuck Berry move.

Now, hold the notes and kick up the gain, and you'll get the difference between those two notes acting up. I think that's what he's doing, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @VarLogRant I know about this one but its way to long to acomplish in the time interval you hear it. The best I tried was hitting the tremolo bar upwards (it releases immediately and produces this springy sound).